# EF6 InvalidOperationException on Update, but works after manual DB Change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update an entity's FK. I am doing it like this:

```
myEntity.FK_ID= Guid.Parse("aff4b5d9-e197-4f0d-85ff-b04464d9e4f0"); //Entity with this Guid exists inside the DB
myEntity.ForeignKeyProperty= null;
```

Then I try to update the entity (new context) like this:

```
using (MyContext db = new MyContext ())
{
    //db.Benutzer.Attach(entity); // <-- Same Exception
    db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

This results in a InvalidOperationException:

```
A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'MyTable.MyTable_ID' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'MyEntity.FK_ID' on the other end.
```

I really don't know why. I then tried the following:
I changed the value of FK_ID to the target value inside the Database. This worked (okay, EF chaching some stuff maybe...)
But then I rechanged the value to something else and it STILL works.

After the manual DB change it now works for this one entity EVERYTIME. If I try to update another entity I get the same Exception. Any ideas on why this is happening?!

Regards,
Marcel

EDIT:
Here's a more complete Code:

```
    //In MVC-Controller
Benutzer dbBenutzer = Database.GetBenutzerByID(model.ID_Benutzer);

// ... Do some other changes to the entity

dbBenutzer.ChangeMitarbeiter = null;
dbBenutzer.MitarbeiterChange_ID = CurrentUser.Mitarbeiter_ID;

//...SaveChanges via 
Database.Update<Benutzer>(dbBenutzer);

// In Repository
public static int Update<E>(E entity) where E : class
{
    using (Context db = new MMVContext())
    {
        try
        {
            db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;  //EXCEPTION                      
            return SaveRepositoryChanges<E>(db);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logging.Error(e.ToExtString());
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the FK you are trying to assign on the other table? I mean is there another entity with the FK aff4b5d9-e197-4f0d-85ff-b04464d9e4f0?

Comment: Yes the Guid exists in the table ... all the Data i try to assign exist

Comment: show the rest of the code as in one part you have myEntity and other you have just entity. how are you using it, where is it being created?

Comment: why not isntead of assigning the value you try to assign the object that has that FK and then update the context? Have you tried that one?

Comment: I added a more complete Code example. I tried to add an entity to the NavigationProperty, but the result was the same => Exception. Even setting both (Entity and FK) resulted in an exception.